# How to make ellipsis image visible in css on click?

Tags: html, css, onclick, hover, ellipsis

I have a screeshot below which I have replicated in CSS.  On **clicking ellipsis image**, I can see list of drop-down items in it. I have put arrow-mark there **(in order to make the question clear which is not part of the requirement)** because on click **I want the ellipsis image to be visible**.

[image]

I have replicated above image in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6pa4ed0/8/embedded/result/) **(with ellipsis at the extreme right)**. On click, I can see list of drop-down items in it with ellipsis image hidden. 

The snippets of **HTML code** which have used in order make the **ellipsis and align the ellipsis** are as follows:

```
<form class="back">
   <input type="text" name="search" class="extand">
   <span class=" fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
   <div style="">
      <img tabindex="1" src="https://s18.postimg.cc/d46ks4xjd/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <li><a href="#">View Status</a><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
         <li><a href="#">Release Bills</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Add Attendee</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Export as</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">View in Google Sheets</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Send Notifications</a></li>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS code in the fiddle so that **on click I can see the ellipsis image** (as marked by an arrow in the 1st image).

At this moment, on click of an ellipsis image, I can only see the drop-down with list of items in it with no ellipsis image.

Comment: no sure if you want to see the existing ellipsis or a new one.  If existing you could just add something like:     margin-top: 40px to the .dropdown class.

Comment: If you want as part of the dropdown, add `<img tabindex="1" src="https://s18.postimg.cc/d46ks4xjd/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">` to a new li above View Status and float: right;

Comment: Can you update it in the fiddle ?. I am summarizing my q one more time as there was a typo in some of the lines. On click, when I see the drop-down list, the ellipsis becomes invisible. Is there any way, we can make it visible while seeing the drop-down list on click ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u6pa4ed0/11/

Comment: @user2796515 In your fiddle, the drop-down now starts from the bottom of the rectangle border.  Is there any way on click, we can make the ellipsis visible without changing the position of the drop-down menu ?

Comment: @user5447339 In my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6pa4ed0/8/embedded/result/), like on click of an ellipsis image it becomes invisible. Is there any way, we can make it visible ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u6pa4ed0/12/   This was my second example - you may need to change your ellipsis image or something though for #ellipsis2.  I made it background black so it would be visible over the white background of the div.

Comment: @user2796515 I don't think your ellipsis is going invisible - I think your list items are in front of the ellipsis.  It is possible to still show the ellipsis (my 2nd example) but it is white on white then and again "appears" invisible.